# Android spinner don't show selected text while list appears in drop down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

i am newbie in android and i am trying to use two spinner views in an activity. entries are showing in drop down of spinner but when i select an entry, it doesn't appear in spinner control. I have searched all over but it didn't work for me. following is all i am doing/trying.
My activity xml is as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_seventy_thirty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.elecsysindia.montestapp.SeventyThirtyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Division"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtDivison"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerDivision"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtDivison"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDivison"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtDivison" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Station"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDivison"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtStationCode"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerStation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDivision"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinnerDivision"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinnerDivision"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinnerStation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerStation"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in class:

```
private static List<String> listDivisions = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String>  listStation = new ArrayList<>();
Spinner spinnerDivision ;
Spinner spinnerStation;
Button btnSubmit;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDivision;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seventy_thirty);
    spinnerDivision = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDivision);
    spinnerStation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStation);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
   // adapterDivision = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listDivisions);
    adapterDivision = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.layout_spinner_item,listDivisions);

    adapterDivision.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerDivision.setAdapter(adapterDivision);
    adapterDivision.notifyDataSetChanged();

    adapterStation = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listStation);
    adapterStation.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerStation.setAdapter(adapterStation);
    adapterStation.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this is how lists are updated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subs.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject subsDetail = subs.getJSONObject(i);
                    ArrayList<String> stnList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    if(subsDetail != null){
                        stnList.clear();
                        String DivCode = subsDetail.getString("divCode");
                        JSONArray st = subsDetail.getJSONArray("stncode");
                        String city="";
                        for (int j=0 ; j<st.length(); j++){
                            stnList.add(st.getString(j));
                            city = city.concat(st.getString(j)+"-");
                        }
                        mapSubscriptions.put(DivCode,stnList);
                        listDivisions.add(DivCode);
                        listStation.addAll(stnList);
```

I am getting data from simple php script and this data is getting inserted to lists.

Also after searching related issue in Sof, i have tried to use a separate layout for spinner as used in

```
adapterDivision = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.layout_spinner_item,listDivisions);
```

but still of no use. 
xml file for layout_spinner_item is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerItem"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#aaddaa"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

I even tried to make text color change in theme itself by setting property android:textColor. but again no success.

```
<item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
```

can you please help me why text is not appearing in spinner control.

After a lot of struggle, text in one spinner is appearing but that appears only if i restart activity directly , i mean without navigating to activity from main activity. 
second spinner (spinnerStation) dont show the text at all. even same source code for both spinners. please see screen shots.
[text appear in spinnerDivision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVJdn.png)

[Entries of spinnerStation which dont show text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ4gw.png)

Comment: Remove adapterStation.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); and check;

Comment: can you please add screenshot too what is the problem you are facing may be i am not really able to understand this is it on click of spinner item you are not able to see text in spinner or something else

Comment: Do you got selected value in `onItemSelected` method?

Comment: @santoshkumar  i tried to comment setDropDownViewResource as you suggested, but it didnt help.  when i select on an item in spinner , the selected item doesnt show up in spinner.

Comment: @Wizard  I get text for first spinner (spinnerDivision) in onItemSelected but for second spinner(spinnerStation)  i get null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to programmatically select the position.
Like this

```
spinnerObject.setSelection(INDEX);
```

And, you should change this

```
 adapterDivision = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.layout_spinner_item,listDivisions);
```

to this,

```
adapterDivision = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,listDivisions);
```

The problem is, your adapter is not getting TextView from custom layout file

Comment: Thanks @Milind for your reply. I tried the same but still text is not appearing in spinner. this is what i have tried.       'spinnerDivision.setSelection(1);
        spinnerStation.setSelection(1);    '                                                       I tried to set selection in onCreate , onResume and also onStart().. but it didn't help

Comment: i tried this  but not working. One thing i noticed that when i make small change in current activity and apply quick changes using studio, it just restarts current activity and spinnerDivision shows text but spinnerStation don't show at all. but if i restart app and move to this activity then both spinners dont show text